# Python 3.4.3 Tkinter TTK file not opening

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4, ttk

When I double click the .pyw file it doesn't run the code and open the GUI. It worked in 2.7 but I don't know.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (180 ,200))
root.title('Title Headder')

def run1():
    #os.startfile("scripts\test.pyw")
    print("Hello")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding=("6 6 12 12"))
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#spacers
ttk.Label(root,text='  ')

ttk.Label(mainframe, text=u"Title", anchor='center',font=("NK57 Monospace", 28, "underline")).grid(in_=mainframe,column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)

#spacers
ttk.Label(root,text='  ').grid(in_=mainframe,column=0, row=2, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)

#buttons

ttk.Button(mainframe,text = "Button", command=run1).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=N)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Button").grid(in_=mainframe,column=0, row=4, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Button").grid(in_=mainframe,column=0, row=5, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)

#spacers
ttk.Label(root,text='  ').grid(in_=mainframe,column=0, row=6, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text=u"Created by TheEvil_potato", anchor='center',font=("NK57 Monospace", 10)).grid(in_=mainframe,column=0, row=7, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I've added the code as I had forgotten. Sorry for that and all answers are appreciated.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that `Tkinter` changed to `tkinter` in Python3. However since you haven't posted your code, it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I'll edit it now.

Comment: What OS? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, but I have an idea what's causing it.

My guess is that your OS runs `.pyw` files using py2. You can double check this in your registry (assuming Windows). Check the following key

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command
```

And change its `default` value to

```
"C:\Python34\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Or wherever your Python3 installation lives. My guess is that, like mine, it currently reads

```
"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Which launches the script with Python2, throws an immediate `ImportError` since `tkinter` is `Tkinter` on Python2, and exits without further issue.

Comment: Thank's, It was 2.7 interfering with it.